# Export report using BIRT

Tags: java, birt

I created a simple application using spring/flex/Java EE.

Now I am looking to how to extract report into pdf format using BIRT.

I am new to BIRT. Is there a way to create something like a button in my application in order to export to pdf format?

Comment: how do you display your report now, where exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Simulant I'd like a user clicking a GUI button calls (with or without parameters) Java side service that opens the viewer Birt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the Birt-Web-Viewer on your server you can use a simple html link to display the Birt Viewer with a link like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/birt_install_folder/frameset?__report=report_folder/report_name.rptdesign&__format=pdf
```

you can use `__format=pdf` to display the report as `pdf`. You can also append report input parameters in this way `&parametername=value`. You could also call a prameterized service create the URL in Java and redirect the user to the URL.

To Save the generated `pdf` to a file your could use the following java code to get the generated `pdf` as an `InputStream`, save it to a file and afterwards start a download for it:

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8080/birt_install_folder/frameset?__report=report_folder/report_name.rptdesign&__format=pdf";
GetMethod method = new GetMethod(urlString);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
InputStream ret = null;
try {
    client.executeMethod(method);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(method.getResponseBody());
    //TODO use InputStream to create a file and start a download
} catch (Excpetion e){
  //log exception
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to save it as pdf format automaticallay ?

Comment: @user204: updated my answer to add a way to get the report a inputStream.